# Why are methods called first when their returns are passed as parameters to other methods?

Tags: java

I have created two classes called clz1(main) & clz2.

clz1:

```
public class clz1 {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        clz2 clz2object=new clz2();
        clz2object.display();
    }

    ...

}
```

clz2:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class clz2 {

    input=new Scanner(System.in);

    public String print1(){
        System.out.print("What is your name:");
        String a=input.next();
        return a;
    }

    public String print2(){
        System.out.print("What is your girlfriend's name:");
        String b=input.next();
        return b;
    }

    public void display(){
        System.out.println("Your name is "+print1()+" & your girlfriend's name is "+print2());
    }

}
```

and the output is like this:

```
What is your name:aaa
What is your girlfriend's name:www
Your name is aaa & your girlfriend's name is www
```

how could this be possible? I didn't call `print1()` and `print2()` ... first this should print *"your name is" and print1()* ....then *"your girlfriend's name is" and print2()* ...isn't it?

Comment: May be it evaluates print1() and print2() prior to concat?

Comment: @user2986468 By the way, consider using proper Java naming conventions: Traditionally, class names start with capital letters.

Answer (score 3):

Your output makes sense. You *did* call `print1()` and `print2()`. You called them in this line:

```
System.out.println("Your name is "+print1()+" & your girlfriend's name is "+print2());
```

When that line executes, the effect is: first `print1()` is called, then `print2()`, then their return values (the user input) are used to build the longer string, then that string is passed to `System.out.println()` which prints the whole thing.

**The reason this happens is because the string parameter must be fully built before it is passed to a method like `System.out.println()` -- this is the way Java works.** So everything that needs to happen in order to fully build that string happens *before* the string is sent to `System.out.println()`.

If the order of operations here confuses you, there are two ways to think about it. One is the above can be rewritten to look like this:

```
String s = "Your name is " + print1() + " & your girlfriend's name is " + print2();
System.out.println(s);
```

Which can be broken down even more into:

```
String s1 = print1();
String s2 = print2();
String s = "Your name is " + s1 + " & your girlfriend's name is " + s2;
System.out.println(s);
```

And if you look at that, the order is very clear. That is essentially what is happening, you just took a shortcut by specifying everything in one statement.

The second way to think about it is more conceptual: In order for you to be able to build the final output string and pass it to `System.out.println()`, you *have* to know what the return values of `print1()` and `print2()` are, otherwise you can't build the string! Therefore, they *have* to be executed first.

If you want to get technical, this behavior is described in a few places in the Java Language Specification. From [Section 8.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1):

> When the method or constructor is invoked (§15.12), the values of the
>   actual argument expressions initialize newly created parameter
>   variables, each of the declared type, **before execution of the body of
>   the method or constructor.**

In other words, Java will fully build your string before `System.out.println()` does its work -- and in your case, that requires calling your print methods.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println("Your name is "+print1()+" & your girlfriend's name is "+print2());
```

You did call print1() and print2(). Java process code in your bracket first, then print it.
It pretty much same like:

```
System.out.println(1+1);
```

It process '1+1' first, then print it later on.

Answer (score 0):

When you call display, display calls print1 and print2

```
display();

public void display(){
    System.out.println("Your name is "+print1()+" & your girlfriend's name is "+print2());

                                        ^^^                                       ^^^
}
```

Before the method returns anything, The actions of print1 will be performed

```
public String print1(){
    System.out.print("What is your name:");   // perform before return
    String a=input.next();
    return a;
}
```

So before anything is returned from print1 and print2, their actions are performed.

Steps for `System.out.println("Your name is "+print1()+" & your girlfriend's name is "+print2());`

> 1) perform `print1` return value to `println`; cannot print line until `print2` is completed
>
> 2) perform  `print2` return value to `println`
>
> 3) print line with return values of `print1` and `print2`

So ultimately, `println` cannot perform because it's performance is based on the calls to other methods. Once those methods complete their actions, then `println` can perform.

Comment: I think Op wanted to know why it does not print **Your name is** then call print1()

Comment: I explained that at the bottom with the steps